# Подключение JS скрипта для расширения Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Много чего перерыл и попробовал, результат, в принципе, один - скрипт не работает. Что нужно написать в manifest.json для подключения js скрипта?
выбивает вот такой exception
    `Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-KlxrUJmj8d4h1348ZMraciiaSiTE583BOiEJjVFIaDs='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution`

Сам манифест

```
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "MyFirstApp",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Unet centreon parsing",

"permissions": [ "http://example.by//*" ],

"browser_action": {
  "default_title": "Start Parse",
  "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В на странице надо подключить скрипт с помощь `<script src = "file.js"></script>`
В файле `file.js` делаем то,что необходимо. В моем случае необходимо было подключить скрипт после загрузки всей страницы, тк использовал событие `click` для `<input id = "btn" type = "button">`. В коде html запрещено использовать события и привязывать к ним скрипт. Надеюсь понятно)